# Discrepancy between raster calculator and geomorphic change detection elevation change results

Tags: raster-calculator

I am using two rasters to determine the elevation change in a stream channel.

When I used the Geomorphic Change Detection Software add-in (version 7.4.1), I got a high elevation change of 8.8 ft and a low of -5.5 ft. I  used the raster calculator to determine the difference between the same two raster layers, I got a high elevation change of 4 ft and a low of -4 ft.

What can be causing such a large difference in these results? Is one more trustworthy than the other?